# how to import Excel file in Databricks pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I am trying to import my excel file to PySpark in Azure-DataBricks machine, which I have to move to PySpark Dataframe. I am not able to perform this action. Getting error

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_excel('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/Time_Payments.xlsx')
df_data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data)
```

While performing above action, getting below error.

```
Error : field Additional Information: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'>
```

Need your assistance here.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by the fact that your Excel files either contains a columns with different types inside (e.g. numbers and string) or some of the values are empty and so when turning it into a panda dataframe, it's filling the blank with "NaN" for a numeric column for example. Which cause spark to error when not being able to infer the schema.

Try creating the dataframe with a schema as argument.

Exemple:

```
#Create PySpark DataFrame Schema
p_schema = StructType([StructField('ADDRESS',StringType(),True),StructField('CITY',StringType(),True),StructField('FIRSTNAME',StringType(),True),StructField('LASTNAME',StringType(),True),StructField('PERSONID',DecimalType(),True)])

#Create Spark DataFrame from Pandas
df_person = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, p_schema)
```

But I would recommand using a specific package that handle direct loading of Excel files to a Spark dataframe, without going through Panda:

https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel

Comment: Can you be more precise on this. I am not sure how code can be written for this. If you have sample code, please share. Thanks a lot for your assistance.

Comment: Yes,I have tried this. Code is not working here. I am getting "Invalid syntax "errors